# Send the variable $ to the uploaded php script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

There are pages of user profiles that work on the principle of get_file_content. Every time it is generated. I would not like to touch on the structure of the site and decided to do block ui with preloader.
I figured it out, but the problem arose. The page is generated on request via `$id = $_GET['id']` (`player.php?id=123`). The script I want to use via the preloader is in another file (*stats.php*), because preloader works through AJAX Post + `$(document).ready(function();`, the `$id` variable cannot be passed from `player.php` to `stats.php`) How to be in this case?

**Js output + preload:**

```
function show_stats() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url: "stats.php",
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#stats-block').block({ 
                message: '<div class="la-ball-pulse la-dark"><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>',
                css: {
                    border: 'none', 
                    backgroundColor:'transparent'
                } 
            });
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('.chatonline').show();
            $('#stats-block').unblock();
            $('#stats-moders').html(data);
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the variable in the `data:` option of `$.ajax()`

```
function show_stats() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url: "stats.php",
        data: { id: <?php echo $id; ?> },
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#stats-block').block({ 
                message: '<div class="la-ball-pulse la-dark"><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>',
                css: {
                    border: 'none', 
                    backgroundColor:'transparent'
                } 
            });
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('.chatonline').show();
            $('#stats-block').unblock();
            $('#stats-moders').html(data);
        },
    });
}
```

`stats.php` can then get the ID from `$_POST['id']`.

Another option is to set a session variable. `player.php` can get `$_SESSION['id'] = $id;`, then `stats.php` can read `$_SESSION['id']`.

If you need to ensure that the ID is the same in both scripts, the session variable is better. The user can easily change the ID in the Javascript.

If there's a possibility that `$id` could be something other than a simple number, you should encode it to ensure proper syntax:

```
data: { id: <?php echo json_encode($id); ?> },
```

Comment: I'll try. Thank you for your prompt response!

Comment: If `$id` is a simple integer or something and will always have a value, should be fine. But to make it more bulletproof, you could do a `json_encode` on the variable to be sure you'll always end up with valid javascript. This is especially helpful with strings, since it handles escaping quotes and stuff for you.

Comment: From the example he gave, it looks like it should always be an integer, so the added generality is not necessary.

Comment: @Barmar IMHO it's always *best & therefore necessary*

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I disagree that it's always necessary, but I've added information about this to the answer.